# Out of range value for column 'ownerid' at row 1 node.js sql query

Tags: sql, node.js, discord.js

I am using  a mysql pool here and I did a query inside of a query. This is supposed to save the guildowner ID in the database when this command is run. Unfortunately it does not let me run this code for some reason. I listed the error down below.

```
var mysql = require("mysql");
var pool  = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit : 10,
  host            : 'localhost',
  user            : '',
  password        : '',
  database        : ''
});
exports.run = (client, message, args) => {
 var oid = message.guild.owner.id;
 var sql = `SELECT * from esite WHERE ownerid = ${message.guild.owner.id}`;
 pool.query(sql,  function (err, row) {
     if(err) throw err;
        if (row && row.length ) {
            console.log('Case row was found!');
            // do something with your row variable
        } else {
            console.log('No case row was found :( !');
               var sql2 = `INSERT INTO esite (ownerid) VALUES ?`;
               var values = [
                [`${message.guild.owner.id}`]
                ];
                pool.query(sql2, [values], function (err) {
                     if(err) throw err;
                   });
        }
    });
}
```

**Error:**

```
Error: ER_WARN_DATA_OUT_OF_RANGE: Out of range value for column 'ownerid' at row 1
    at Query.Sequence._packetToError (/root/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:47:14)
    at Query.ErrorPacket (/root/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:79:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/root/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:291:23)
    at Parser._parsePacket (/root/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:433:10)
    at Parser.write (/root/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:43:10)
    at Protocol.write (/root/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:38:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/root/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:88:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/root/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:302:12)
    --------------------
    at Pool.query (/root/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:199:23)
    at Query.<anonymous> (/root/dc/DHL/commands/esite.js:23:22)
    at Query.<anonymous> (/root/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10)
    at Query._callback (/root/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:488:16)
    at Query.Sequence.end (/root/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:83:24)
    at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (/root/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:149:8)
    at Query.EofPacket (/root/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:133:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/root/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:291:23)
    at Parser._parsePacket (/root/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:433:10)
    at Parser.write (/root/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:43:10) {
  code: 'ER_WARN_DATA_OUT_OF_RANGE',
  errno: 1264,
  sqlMessage: "Out of range value for column 'ownerid' at row 1",
  sqlState: '22003',
  index: 0,
  sql: "INSERT INTO esite (ownerid) VALUES ('407206318911258628')"
}
```

Comment: What is the OwnerID data type?

Comment: @Sparky owner id is an integer, it is a discord user id

Comment: What is message object ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The largest integer value allowed in mySQL int data type is 4294967295.

If you change the data type to BIGINT, your value will work.

See this page for details

https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-int/